# ASP MVC how bind dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm newbie with ASP.Net MVC 5 and I'm having a problem understanding the dropdownlist.

I want show a form that binds a DTO object (because that form doesn't map one to one a database table). My form must show the following fields:

```
Name (edit box)
Address (edit box)
Type (dropdownlist that show always 3 fixed values: "Type1", "Type2" and "Type3"
```

How can I write my DTO object class and the two Create actions (the one that show the form and the other that handle the post)?

I found some solutions that use the `enum` in the DTO objects, others that use the `viewbag` in the create action (GET)...I'm confused!!!

Comment: You need to show the model with the properties you are binding to.

Comment: I suggest this: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v (edit in part 17)

Answer (score 3):

Trick is to use SelectListItem and use DropDownFor.

Create a property on your view model like

```
public class ViewModel {
  string SelectedItem { get; set; }
  List<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit() {
  var items = new List<SelectListItem>() { 
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Option1Text", Value = "Value1Text"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Option1Text", Value = "Value1Text"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Option1Text", Value = "Value1Text"}};
  var model = new ViewModel() { Items = items };

  return View(model);
};
```

In your view

```
@model ViewModel

@Html.DropDownFor(x => x.SelectedItem, Model.Items)
```

You can then get the selected value in your action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel model) {
   var whatWasSelected = model.SelectedItem; // This will be "OptionXValue"
   // Do more things
}
```

You should also re-populate the select list items on whatever action responds to the form submission if you're going to re-render the view. This is because the collection of options are not transmitted over the original request and therefore ASP.NET MVC doesn't know how to rebuild the collection by itself. By doing this you'll avoid any nasty exceptions when trying to set the selected item in the collection of SelectListItem. Overall the responding action would look more like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel model) {
  var items = new List<SelectListItem>() { 
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Option1Text", Value = "Value1Text"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Option1Text", Value = "Value1Text"},
    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Option1Text", Value = "Value1Text"}};
   model.Items = items;

   var whatWasSelected = model.SelectedItem; // This will be "OptionXValue"
   // Do more things
}
```